# Orbital phase and gravitational wave phase

Tags: general-relativity, orbital-motion, spherical-harmonics, linearized-theory, binary-stars

I am trying to understand the relation between the orbital phase of binary and the phase of the gravitational wave when expressed as spin-weighted spherical harmonics.

The metric perturbation can be expressed as the famous quadrupole formula in linearized gravity. Using the Newman-Penrose formalism, the metric can be expressed in null tetrads such that the entire information about the gravitational wave polarizations is captured in a complex scalar $h$. This $h$ can be expanded in spin-weighted spherical harmonics and the dominant is the (2,2) mode. How are these phases of spherical harmonics related to the orbital phase of a binary system? This is the part that I want to understand.